# What does this line of code mean? (LinkedList)

Tags: python, linked-list

**prev = slow.next = None**

I'm assuming it sets prev = slow.next but what is None set to?

Answer (score 1):

It means that `prev` and `slow.next`are both set to `None`.
None is the value for empty Variables and this the the way you can set two variables tot the same value.

For example, if you have x and y coordinates and want to set both to zero, you would write one of this lines:

```py
x = y = 0
y = x = 0
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_multiple.asp)

Answer (score 1):

it's just a simple way to assign `None` to both `slow.next` and `prev`

ie

```
prev = slow.next = None
```

is equivalent to

```
prev = None
slow.next = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignments are also expressions that represent the value on the right side of the `=`. Furthermore, the evaluation begins from the rightmost assignments, so `slow.next` is set to `None`, and the assignment itself evaluates to `None`, which is what `prev` is then set to.

Answer (score 0):

It means both prev and slow.next are assigned None value.